# Implementing gui from another project

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two programs that each have graphic user interfaces. I combined these programs into 1 graphic user interface by creating a new project all together, adding the two projects to the new project's build path, and adding the panels from these projects onto the new project's gui.

The problem I have now is the functions that these panels call work just fine, but the variable that they are getting the form data from is the original form inside the separate programs main function. With the new implementation this main is never actually called so those forms do not exist. Rather they exist in my new program.

I cannot add the new program to the old programs build path, because that would make it circular, so how do I get the functions to see the new program's form it was created by?

Sorry that was a wall of text.. let me know if I need to clarify something.

Comment: Why not refactor the programs ? If you use eclipse you could probably live with the circular dependency for a while: http://firas.bessadok.com/circular-dependencies-forcing-eclipse-to-compile-projects/

Comment: By refactor do you mean merge the two programs into one? Also, I'd like to avoid a wrong way of doing this if possible.

Comment: avoiding the wrong way is always a good idea ;-) You have some options: you could export the needed components and import them into your third project. Or move source code between projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this by making the form objects I needed in my new gui. I initialized these by calling on the main functions and the form from those functions. Something like this:

```
static DataForm dataTab = com.company.folder.Main.form;
```

That is with DataForm being one of the two previous graphic user interfaces. Now the programs are able to run alone or with the new interface which puts them as tabs.